# The ${this...} doesn't show values in Node v13.14

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the Class Property values don't appear in Console when i execute this code? Many thanks.

```
class Pessoa
{
  constructor(nome, idade)
  {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }

  Info()
  {
    console.log('O meu nome é ${this.nome} e tenho ${this.idade} anos.');
  }
}

p1 = new Pessoa("Pedro", 49);
p1.Info();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `${expression}` [template string syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you must use the `` ` `` character, not the `'`.

```js
class Pessoa
{
  constructor(nome, idade)
  {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }

  Info()
  {
    console.log(`O meu nome é ${this.nome} e tenho ${this.idade} anos.`);
  }
}

p1 = new Pessoa("Pedro", 49);
p1.Info();
```